# Ошибка при использовании <Route>

Tags: webpack, react-router

При использовании реактовского компонента а именно
 Route выдает ошибку

```
 Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8080/portfolio/src/bundle.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

Вот код моего компонента

```
const AppRouter = () => (
<BrowserRouter>
<div>
  <Header />
  <Switch>
    <Route path='/' component={Home} exact={true} />
    <Route path="/portfolio/:id" component={PortfolioItem} />
    <Route path='/contact' component={Contact} />        
    <Route component={Error} />
  </Switch>
</div>
```

)

То есть когда я перехожу на /contact ошибки нет никакой , но как только я хочу динамически переходить допустим на /portfolio/55 вылазит ошибка.
Пытался нагуглить пишут не правильно настроен webpack.
Вот минимальные настройки webpack

```
module.exports = {

entry: './src/app.js',

output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist'),
    filename: "bundle.js"
},
devtool: 'source-map',
devServer:{
    historyApiFallback: true,

},
module:{
    rules:[
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader:'babel-loader'


        },
        {
            test: /\.s?css$/,
            use:['style-loader','css-loader', 'sass-loader']

        }

    ]

},
plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template:'./src/index.html'

    })
]
```

}

Answer (score 0):

В настройках webpack нужно было добавить publicPath: '/'